# rails_admin export not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I am trying to use the export function in rails_admin. If I click on the export button the following error appears:

```
c:/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails_admin-0.6.8/app/views/rails_admin/main/export.html.haml where line #51 raised:
```

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Extracted source (around line #51):

```
48         %i.icon-chevron-down
49         = t('admin.export.options_for', name: 'csv')
50       .form-group.control-group
51         - guessed_encoding = @abstract_model.encoding
52         %label.col-sm-2.control-label{for: "csv_options_encoding_to"}=  t('admin.export.csv.encoding_to')
53         .col-sm-10.controls
54           -# from http://books.google.com/support/partner/bin/answer.py?answer=30990 :
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by commenting out lines 51 and 56.

```
50 .form-group.control-group 
51 -# guessed_encoding = @abstract_model.encoding 
52 %label.col-sm-2.control-label{for: "csv_options_encoding_to"}= t('admin.export.csv.encoding_to') 
53 .col-sm-10.controls 
54 -# from http://books.google.com/support/partner/bin/answer.py?answer=30990 : 
55 = select_tag 'csv_options[encoding_to]', options_for_select(RailsAdmin::CSVConverter::TARGET_ENCODINGS), include_blank: true 
56 -# %p.help-block= t('admin.export.csv.encoding_to_help', name: guessed_encoding)
```